# Surf 3D Matrix size issue

Tags: matlab, plot

currently i try to understand some code i got from my supervisor in college. My task is to create a 3D plot. I've got vector V.x with dimension 1x41 and a vector V.y with dimension 1x41 as well. Besides that i got a 3D Matrix E with the dimension 41x41x301. 
I tried to use surf(V.x,V.y,E).
I get an error because of the dimensions must agree. 
Where is the Problem? Is it because of the "x301", because E is a 3D Matrix?
If so, how can i fix it?
My next thought was to transpose either V.x or V.y but i still dont have the 301.

Sincerely
Lucas

Comment: If you could provide us some more information or the source code it would be easier to try to explain. What do you mean by a 3D plot? Is it a surface plot or a 3D curve? The function you want to plot appears to be a function of 2 variables (`x` and `y`). Is it correct? If so, the size of the E matrix is wrong. Perhaps you have a 3rd parameters and want to see the function `F(x,y)` for different values of this parameter, which explains the third dimension of the E matrix. Either way, some information is missing. You should check your supervisor instructions or betterread the code documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but try `surf(V.x,V.y,squeeze(E(:,:,1)))`

That should do a surf plot of the first "layer" of the 3D matrix E. If it doesn't work, post an update here with the error(s).